# Indexes not used

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two different table `ACCOUNTS` AND `STATUS`

```
ACCOUNTS:
========
ACCT_NUM
ACCT_TYPE
BALANCE
ACCT_NAME
BRANCH
BANK_ID

STATUS:
=======
ACCT_NUM
ACCT_STATUS
STATUS_DATE
BANK_ID
```

Accounts table more than 1 million records, has `ACCT_NUM` as index and `BANK_ID` as one more index.
`STATUS` table has 1 million records and has `ACCT_NUM`,`BANK_ID` index.

I wanted to select all the with Status as "I" Inactive, So I wrote the query as below.

```
SELECT A.ACCT_NUM,A.BALANCE,B.ACCT_STATUS 
FROM ACCOUNTS A, STATUS B
WHERE A.ACCT_NUM = B.ACCT_NUM
AND A.BANK_ID = B.BANK_ID
```

From explain plan i could see the STATUS index is not being used and going under table full access.
Can anyone explain why indexes are not being used and how could i improve the performance of this query.

Comment: There is no filter

Comment: @GurwinderSingh But doesnt the join use the index ?

Comment: I think the problem is table only have 10 rows, so index doesnt really change anything.

Comment: What in your query do you think is limiting to "Status as 'I' Inactive", as you wrote in your question?  What percentage of your records are active vs inactive?  If a high percentage (over 10%) are inactive, the answer to your "why does Oracle not use my index" is that using an index would actually be _slower_.  Full table scans and hash joins are _very_ efficient -- more efficient, usually, than reading and joining even as little as 10% of the data via indexes.

Comment: Actually i have used some filter as well, B.ACCT_STATUS = 'I' AND B.STATUS < sysdate -6.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak, You are correct, ACCT_STATUS with Active will be 70% and Inactive would 30% and no nulls and my query is under going FULL Table Scan and the cost of the query is high. Can you suggest any method to Reduce the cost of the query.

Comment: @SrikanthKurmala Generally, I would accept a full table scan with hash joins in this situation.  10 lahks is just a million rows, right?  How fast do you need this thing to go, and why?  If you have a legitimate reason to speed it up, you could look at two options: (1) a "covering index" on one or both your tables and (2) storing accounts and status in a cluster to reduce physical I/Os.  These are extraordinary steps that I would not even look at without a demonstrated reason to improve the performance over what full-scans with hash joins is giving.

Comment: @SrikanthKurmala Also, I see from your other comment you are limiting to rows in the past 6 days?  Is there an index on `STATUS.STATUS`?  If not, create one.  That way, Oracle can get the few rows from `STATUS` that meet your 6 day condition and then look up the few matches in `ACCOUNTS` via indexes.

Comment: as you can see, using Indian numbering system caused people to think that there's only 10 rows in the table instead of a million. Please don't do that.

Comment: have you tried using optimizer hints? You can explicitly force oracle optimizer to use the index as required, if it is not using one